# rails redirect_to stuck at 302 after logging in

Tags: ruby, authentication, ruby-on-rails-4, redirect

I am creating an app using lessons from the Michael Hartl book. I used his login functionality which looks like this

sessions_controller.rb

```
def create
    user = User.find_by(email: params[:session][:email].downcase)
    if user && user.authenticate(params[:session][:password])
      log_in user
      params[:session][:remember_me] == '1' ? remember(user) : forget(user)
      redirect_to home_path
    else
      flash.now[:danger] = 'Invalid email/password combination'
      render 'new'
    end
  end
```

After the user is logged in it should redirect to /home but for some unknown reason it is stuck in 302 and I'm not really sure why and when it started doing this. I've been implementing without going back to the log in functionality. Tried running rails test it appears to be green.

Stuck at 302

```
  User Load (4.1ms)  SELECT  "users".* FROM "users" WHERE "users"."email" = $1 LIMIT $2  [["email", "alex@halo.com"], ["LIMIT", 1]]
  ↳ app/controllers/sessions_controller.rb:7
   (2.1ms)  BEGIN
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:62
   (1.8ms)  COMMIT
  ↳ app/models/user.rb:62
Redirected to http://localhost:3000/selected
Completed 302 Found in 106ms (ActiveRecord: 12.6ms)
```

Line 62 user.rb

```
def forget
    update_attribute(:remember_digest, nil)
end
```

Another weird thing, going to /home on a new tab shows that the user is logged in, when I log out and log in again on that new tab it's stuck again. When I refresh the page when it's stuck it redirects me to /home as expected, when I log out and tries to log in again I'm not stuck anymore. So for some reason the redirect is stuck only on the first login attempt of a new tab.

Please if anyone can help me solve/debug this problem I would be very grateful.

Comment: You need to provide the code behind `remember`, `forget` and `log_in` methods in order to get adequate answer. Also how does you'r home controller look like?